# Can't stop function execution when submitting a form with required fields not filled

Tags: javascript, validation, submit, form-submit

it's probably a simple logic problem and I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't find why.

When my form is submitted i'm using a little API to send a mail with some JS code (emailJS). I can make the html say "Please fill out this field" but the mail is still sended.

I tried with preventDefault and stopImmediatePropagation :

HTML

```
<label for="watts1">Device 1:</label>
<input type="number" required/>
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Send form"/>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    // e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    
    form.subject = `${form.name} ${form.surname} ...`
    form.body = `${form.name} ${form.surname} ...`


    Email.send({
        SecureToken: "***",
        To: "***",
        From: `***`,
        Subject: `${form.subject}`,
        Body: `${form.body}`,
    }).then((message) => alert(message));
});
```

I'm pretty new to coding, I found much solutions on different websites for any previous issue but here I'd like to find an easy way to make it instead of weird solutions that I can't yet understand.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try preventing default on form **submit** handler

Comment: `preventDefault` prevents the default action and does not stop your sending, since it is a click event and not a submit event. `stopImmediatePropagation` stops the event forwarding and again, does not stop your sending. A simple `if` should suffice. However, be aware that everyone can copy your send call to the console and send mails eitherway (theoretically).

Comment: `document.getElementById("formID").addEventListener("submit", function (e) { e.preventDefault();` HTML5 validation works on submit events

Comment: You're not making any validaiton. Check if `form.name` and `form.surname` are like you expect (like, minimum character count etc.), and if not, use `return;` before `Email.send`, that will break the function's execution.

Comment: @mplungjan It's an AJAX call and not a submit event. Cant see how `preventDefault` would stop anything since the actual submit is irrelevant.

Comment: @JavaScript see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68359202/295783)

Comment: @JavaScript See my UPDATED answer

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 `required` validation normally works on submit events

If you do not want a form, you can check the validity of the field:

Note I changed the button to type="button"

```js
document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (document.getElementById("number").checkValidity()) {

    console.log("sending"); // never reached if number is empty
    /*
      Email.send({
        SecureToken: "***",
        To: "***",
        From: `***`,
        Subject: `${form.subject}`,
        Body: `${form.body}`,
      }).then((message) => alert(message));
      */
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="watts1">Device 1:</label>
<input type="number" required id="number" />
<input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send form" />
```

Using form submit event

```js
document.getElementById("formID").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // necessary here
  console.log("sending"); // never reached if number is empty
  /*
    Email.send({
      SecureToken: "***",
      To: "***",
      From: `***`,
      Subject: `${form.subject}`,
      Body: `${form.body}`,
    }).then((message) => alert(message));
    */
});
```

```html
<form id="formID">
  <label for="watts1">Device 1:</label>
  <input type="number" required/>
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Send form" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, the second solution is exactly the logic I missed, much thanks !